# Is it possible to minus my table rows value based on param until it hits zero without looping?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let's say I have `spCalculate` with `@amount` as parameter.

I have `STOCK` table with following rows

```
----------------
STOCKID | AMOUNT
----------------
      1 |     50
      2 |     70
      3 |     20
```

spCalculate will minus the `AMOUNT` from `STOCK` until the `@amount` value hit zero. For example if `@amount` is `100` then the final result would be

```
----------------
STOCKID | AMOUNT
----------------
      1 |      0
      2 |     20
      3 |     20
```

If `@amount` is `30`, then

```
----------------
STOCKID | AMOUNT
----------------
      1 |     20
      2 |     70
      3 |     20
```

if `@amount` is `130`, then

```
----------------
STOCKID | AMOUNT
----------------
      1 |      0
      2 |      0
      3 |     10
```

How to achieve this without looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `CROSS APPLY`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be237/4/0)

```
UPDATE s
    SET AMOUNT = CASE
                    WHEN r IS NULL THEN 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN amount - @amount < 0 THEN 0 
                            ELSE amount - @amount
                        END
                    WHEN AMOUNT - r < 0 THEN 0
                    ELSE AMOUNT - r
                END
FROM STOCK s
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT r = @amount - SUM(AMOUNT)
    FROM STOCK
    WHERE STOCKID < s.STOCKID
)x
WHERE R IS NULL OR R > 0
```

Comment: apologize for stupid question, but I've look around CROSS APPLY but I don't understand how does this line works? `WHERE STOCKID < s.STOCKID`

Comment: It's a correlated subquery. The first `STOCKID` pertains to the `STOCK` inside the subquery(`CROSS APPLY`), `s.STOCKID` refers to the outer `STOCK` table, the one in `FROM` clause.

Comment: Ok got it! I have another case where instead of using `STOCKID`, I have a `date` column and it will minus the lowest date first and if there's more than one column with same date, it will use the lowest `AMOUNT`. How do I achieve this? I've tried using `ORDER BY` inside `CROSS APPLY` but it won't let me.

Comment: nvm i did it by using ROW_NUMBER()